Python function to read doc file
I am working on a program in Python to read a doc/docx file. I found a module named docx, so I tried this function:
import docx
#funct to get text from doc
def getText(file_name):
    try:
        doc = Document(file_name)
        fullText = []
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            fullText.append(para.text)
        return '\n'.join(fullText)
    except:
        print(doc.paragraphs)
        print("Exception")
        return

I keep getting the same Exception output, and if I try to print the output
text = getText(file)
 print(str(text))

it just prints None.
The exception I got during debugging is PackageNotFoundError, so in the code I encapsulated the getText function in a try-except block.
I tried saving the files locally, since they are located in a remote dropbox folder, and if I save ithe files locally and open it with word I found out they are empty.
pth = os.path.abspath('files/' + fname.split('/')[-1]) #fname.split... is the dropbox .docx file name
                if not os.path.isfile(pth): #check I have not already saved the file in older debugging
                    doc = Document()
                    doc.save(pth)
                text = getText(pth)

I guess the formatting is not recognized by docx. Is there another library to solve this specific problem, or maybe a particular function from the same docx package library?
I considered textract, but I use Windows, and on another laptop with macOS I could not successfully install it.
Edit: I was able to download the content of doc files from dropbox by a function in the API documentation:
def download_file(dbx, path):
##    path = '/%s/%s/%s' % (folder, subfolder.replace(os.path.sep, '/'), name)
##    dest = '/%s/%s' % (folder, subfolder.replace(os.path.sep, '/'))
    while '//' in path:
        path = path.replace('//', '/')
##    while '//' in dest:
##        dest = dest.replace('//', '/')
    with stopwatch('download'):
        try:
            md,res = dbx.files_download(path)
        except dropbox.exceptions.HttpError as err:
            #print('*** HTTP error', err)
            return None
        except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError:
            #print('** API error', dropbox.exceptions.ApiError)
            return None
    with open(res.content, encoding='CP1252') as data_handle:
    #data = res.content
        s = str(data_handle)
        s_data = StringIO(s)
    #decode unreadable 0x90 byte
    #with codecs.open(s_data, encoding='iso-8859-1') as s_data_handle:
        dataframe = pd.read_html(s_data)
        print(dataframe)
    #print(len(data))
    return data_handle

The last part of decoding I added it because I wanted to download a doc/docx file with formatting and table if present… without it, the content is somewhat readable, but I also get random undecoded characters, possibly because the response content is bytes and not html..
However, I get decoding errors:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Is there a better way to reach my objective? Basically I just want to respect formatting and if possible create a pandas dataframe from it…

I'm not sure what your end goal is but this may help you get started towards it. One issue seems to be you were calling docx incorrectly. From this page python-docx you needed to change the import call.
I have also used PathLib which solves about 99% of all file related issues on any OS. It can be used to handle file paths and names for input and output needs.
Trying to use doc in the except would always throw an error as it was not created in the except step prior to you calling it, I've removed it from my example.
Minimal working example:
from pathlib import Path
from docx import Document
#funct to get text from doc
def getText(file_name):
    try:
        doc = Document(file_name)
        fullText = []
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            fullText.append(para.text)
        return '\n'.join(fullText)
    except Exception as error:
        # If something goes wrong, tell me what happened
        return f"Exception: {error}"
        
file = Path("C:\my folder\myfile.docx")        
        
text = getText(file)
print(text) 



It looks like you are trying to pull the paragraph text from a word document that you have on Drobox. I'll first add a few notes on what your current solution is missing, and then I'll try and propose a solution.

You need to include from docx import Document instead of import docx.
You need to remove the line print(doc.paragraphs) from the Except block. This is because we expect the Except block code to run if the try block code fails. Typically, your try block will fail if running Document(file_name) raises an error. This could happen if python could not find the file referred to by file_name. If running Document(file_name) fails, then the Document function will not return a value to be assigned to doc. This will lead to an UnboundLocalError when you try to run print(doc.paragraphs).
You are getting a PackageNotFoundError because docx can't find the file you are referring to. The string you supply with the file path needs to be either an absolute path, (like "C:\Users\my_user\folder\file.docx") or a relative path. If you supply something like ".\file.docx" for file_name, then python will interpret that as meaning, "file.docx" in the same folder that the script is being run in. If you don't know from where the script will be run, then it's best to just supply the absolute filepath of where you expect the file to be.
It looks like the code where you save the file will always result in an empty file, (unless the file is there already) because of lines 3-4:

doc = Document()
doc.save(path)

Supplying no argument to Document like this will always give you an empty word document.

One other final thing to note is that  will only pull the information contained in paragraphs in the word document. There are many other elements that can contain text in .docx files, such as tables and headers. As long as you are OK with losing this information, we can just scrape the text from document.paragraphs.

Now, it looks like what you want is to be able to scrape the text from a .docx file from Dropbox. There is a Dropbox API that you can use to download files from your Dropbox account. You can see in instructions on how to set that up here.
Once you have the file where you want on your local machine, the following should work:
def getText(file_name):
    doc = Document(file_name)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print(getText("<path to word doc>"))

Assuming that you have supplied a valid path.
